# javascript background size and IE issue

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

I am trying to use javascript to setup background image size.

I have

```
  image.style.backgroundSize = 133+'px '+106+'px'; 
  image.style.backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat';
```

in javascript.

My codes work well in `Chrome` and `FF` but not in `IE 7` and `IE 8`.

I was wondering if there are anyway to remedy this issue. Thanks for the help!

Comment: When you say that this feature "doesn't work", what exactly do you mean? There are a lot of different meanings for this. To help get your problem understood by other users, try adding some code or a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to help.

Answer (score 1):

It does not work because IE7 and IE8 do not support that CSS feature.

http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size